# Quick question about Environment Variables use in SH scripts

Tags: shell, environment-variables, sh

I have found a script to set the background image and do some more stuff, but that's not important.

Look at this line, it's supposed to set a route, nothing complicated.

```
#!/bin/sh
bgloc="${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share/}bg"
```

I didn't understand what was it doing, because of the env variable and the `:-` that comes after it. Now, after some trial and error, I've figured it out. It sets the variable `bgloc` with the value of that env variable and, if that variable is not set —which is the case—, then, it use the route that comes after the `:-` .

So, the question is: why does that happen? I mean, I've searched it on the internet, and I haven't found anything. Is it supposed to work like this? In that case, where can I find information about that? I'd like to learn more about it, but I don't find any information on the internet. Some help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot can be done with values within `${}` in `bash`.

To find out more about these features I would recommend to read [TLDP manual on this topic](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).